# "zlib: inflate error = -3 (data error)" with custom png implementation

Tags: algorithm, png, zlib

I'm implementing a PNG encoder in VHDL for learning purposes. It works with image sizes from 1x1 to 4x4. At the image size of 5x5 there is a behaviour I can't understand:

When encoding raw data with values 0...24, the encoding works. However, when using raw data with values 255...231, it generates a broken image.

Input values 0...24:

```
> hexdump -C png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png
00000000  89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a  00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52  |.PNG........IHDR|
00000010  00 00 00 05 00 00 00 05  08 00 00 00 00 a8 04 79  |...............y|
00000020  39 00 00 00 4c 49 44 41  54 78 01 00 04 00 fb ff  |9...LIDATx......|
00000030  00 00 01 02 00 04 00 fb  ff 03 04 00 05 00 04 00  |................|
00000040  fb ff 06 07 08 09 00 04  00 fb ff 00 0a 0b 0c 00  |................|
00000050  04 00 fb ff 0d 0e 00 0f  00 04 00 fb ff 10 11 12  |................|
00000060  13 00 04 00 fb ff 00 14  15 16 01 02 00 fd ff 17  |................|
00000070  18 0b a4 01 2d d5 1f a2  6d 00 00 00 00 49 45 4e  |....-...m....IEN|
00000080  44 ae 42 60 82                                    |D.B`.|
00000085

> pngcheck -vv png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png 
File: png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png (133 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    5 x 5 image, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00025, length 76
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, superfast compression
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      0 0 0 0 0 (5 out of 5)
  chunk IEND at offset 0x0007d, length 0
No errors detected in png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png (3 chunks, -432.0% compression).
```

Input values 255...231:

```
> hexdump -C png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png
00000000  89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a  00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52  |.PNG........IHDR|
00000010  00 00 00 05 00 00 00 05  08 00 00 00 00 a8 04 79  |...............y|
00000020  39 00 00 00 4c 49 44 41  54 78 01 00 04 00 fb ff  |9...LIDATx......|
00000030  00 ff fe fd 00 04 00 fb  ff fc fb 00 fa 00 04 00  |................|
00000040  fb ff f9 f8 f7 f6 00 04  00 fb ff 00 f5 f4 f3 00  |................|
00000050  04 00 fb ff f2 f1 00 f0  00 04 00 fb ff ef ee ed  |................|
00000060  ec 00 04 00 fb ff 00 eb  ea e9 01 02 00 fd ff e8  |................|
00000070  e7 6a 21 17 bc 9a 17 87  e7 00 00 00 00 49 45 4e  |.j!..........IEN|
00000080  44 ae 42 60 82                                    |D.B`.|
00000085

> pngcheck -vv png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png 
File: png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png (133 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    5 x 5 image, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00025, length 76
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, superfast compression
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):

    zlib: inflate error = -3 (data error)
 (0 out of 5)
ERRORS DETECTED in png_encoder/gen/test_img_no_compression_5x5.png
```

How to interpret the error message `zlib: inflate error = -3 (data error)`?

I read https://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html, but didn't find more specific information. My first guess was the row filters are incorrect, but since both files are structured the same, this is unlikely. Is there  something wrong with the ADLER32 calculation in the second case (possibly some overflow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an overflow in the ADLER32 checksum calculation. Specifically, there were two 16 bit numbers added and truncated before applying the modulo with 65521. Unfortunately my ADLER32 unittest didn't catch it, yet.

However, the error message was shown several times during the implementation and I was always not sure about the cause. If anybody could elaborate the error message or explain how to get a better error message, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: You mean specifically the message "inflate error = -3 (data error)"? zlib actively uses the Adler-32 checksum to verify data was correctly unpacked. If an error occurs *during unpacking* (and it could not be further decompressed) then you would get this error, but if the data unpacks without any errors and this checksum does not match, it can only conclude there was an unexpected error somewhere in the data.

Comment: Yes, I mean this specific error message. It's a bit difficult to find the exact error cause when only knowing something went wrong during decompressing. But I guess it gets better when the implementation gets more stable.